# Bots playing a counting game

Tags: code-golf, number, random

## Introduction

A childhood game designed to help children learn to count in french in Canadian schools is played as follows:

- Students go around the room counting up to 11
- A number greater than 11 cannot be said
- A student can say either 1, 2, or 3 numbers
- If a student says the number 11 then they are removed from the next round and play begins again at 1
- The game continues until there is 1 player remaining

Consider the simple example:

```
Player1 | Player2
01      |
02      |
03      |
        | 04
        | 05
        | 06
07      |
08      |
        | 09
10      |
        | 11
Player 1 wins
```

## The rules

- Design a program which takes in an integer greater than or equal to 2 and less than or equal to 99 (for formatting reasons) and outputs the game played by this number of bots
- Play will begin with bot1 and increase to the highest number bot
- Play will cycle back to the beginning when the final bot is reached
- Bots will randomly output the next 1, 2, or 3 numbers **UNLESS**

  - Outputting 2 or 3 numbers will cause them to lose on that turn.

    - If the count is 8 when it reaches a bot, it should only decide between `9` and `10`
  - Outputting 2 or 3 numbers will cause them to go over 11
- Output numbers and bot numbers should be formatted  to take two characters (i.e. you can format numbers to be `01`, `_1`, or whitespace, whatever makes you happy)
- Each column should be 2 characters wide separated by `|` as well as a `|` at the beginning and ends of rows
- Once a bot is out the remainder of their column should be filled by `xx`
- When there is only one bot remaining he is the winner
- The program will announce which bot was the winner in the form of `Bot #N is the winner`
- This is code-golf so shortest byte count wins

## Formatting examples

```
|01|02|03|
|01|  |  |
|02|  |  |
|03|  |  |
|  |04|  |
|  |  |05|
|  |  |06|
|07|  |  |
|  |08|  |
|  |09|  |
|  |10|  |
|  |  |11|
|01|  |xx|
|02|  |xx|
|03|  |xx|
|  |04|xx|
|  |05|xx|
|06|  |xx|
|  |07|xx|
|08|  |xx|
|  |09|xx|
|  |10|xx|
|11|  |xx|
Bot #2 is the winner
```

**Option**

The outputs can get long so you are permitted to output only the final number of the bots turn for example the above output becomes instead:

```
|01|02|03|
|03|  |  |
|  |04|  |
|  |  |06|
|07|  |  |
|  |10|  |
|  |  |11|
|03|  |xx|
|  |05|xx|
|06|  |xx|
|  |07|xx|
|08|  |xx|
|  |10|xx|
|11|  |xx|
Bot #2 is the winner
```

With 5 bots:

```
|01|02|03|04|05|
|01|  |  |  |  |
|  |04|  |  |  |
|  |  |05|  |  |
|  |  |  |07|  |
|  |  |  |  |10|
|11|  |  |  |  |
|xx|01|  |  |  |
|xx|  |03|  |  |
|xx|  |  |06|  |
|xx|  |  |  |09|
|xx|10|  |  |  |
|xx|  |11|  |  |
|xx|  |xx|02|  |
|xx|  |xx|  |03|
|xx|05|xx|  |  |
|xx|  |xx|07|  |
|xx|  |xx|  |08|
|xx|10|xx|  |  |
|xx|  |xx|11|  |
|xx|  |xx|xx|01|
|xx|03|xx|xx|  |
|xx|  |xx|xx|04|
|xx|07|xx|xx|  |
|xx|  |xx|xx|08|
|xx|10|xx|xx|  |
|xx|  |xx|xx|11|
Bot #2 is the winner
```

With 10 players:

```
|01|02|03|04|05|06|07|08|09|10|
|01|  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
|  |04|  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
|  |  |05|  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
|  |  |  |08|  |  |  |  |  |  |
|  |  |  |  |09|  |  |  |  |  |
|  |  |  |  |  |10|  |  |  |  |
|  |  |  |  |  |  |11|  |  |  |
|  |  |  |  |  |  |xx|02|  |  |
|  |  |  |  |  |  |xx|  |04|  |
|  |  |  |  |  |  |xx|  |  |07|
|09|  |  |  |  |  |xx|  |  |  |
|  |10|  |  |  |  |xx|  |  |  |
|  |  |11|  |  |  |xx|  |  |  |
|  |  |xx|01|  |  |xx|  |  |  |
|  |  |xx|  |02|  |xx|  |  |  |
|  |  |xx|  |  |03|xx|  |  |  |
|  |  |xx|  |  |  |xx|04|  |  |
|  |  |xx|  |  |  |xx|  |07|  |
|  |  |xx|  |  |  |xx|  |  |08|
|09|  |xx|  |  |  |xx|  |  |  |
|  |10|xx|  |  |  |xx|  |  |  |
|  |  |xx|11|  |  |xx|  |  |  |
|  |  |xx|xx|02|  |xx|  |  |  |
|  |  |xx|xx|  |03|xx|  |  |  |
|  |  |xx|xx|  |  |xx|05|  |  |
|  |  |xx|xx|  |  |xx|  |08|  |
|  |  |xx|xx|  |  |xx|  |  |09|
|10|  |xx|xx|  |  |xx|  |  |  |
|  |11|xx|xx|  |  |xx|  |  |  |
|  |xx|xx|xx|03|  |xx|  |  |  |
|  |xx|xx|xx|  |05|xx|  |  |  |
|  |xx|xx|xx|  |  |xx|08|  |  |
|  |xx|xx|xx|  |  |xx|  |10|  |
|  |xx|xx|xx|  |  |xx|  |  |11|
|01|xx|xx|xx|  |  |xx|  |  |xx|
|  |xx|xx|xx|03|  |xx|  |  |xx|
|  |xx|xx|xx|  |06|xx|  |  |xx|
|  |xx|xx|xx|  |  |xx|08|  |xx|
|  |xx|xx|xx|  |  |xx|  |09|xx|
|10|xx|xx|xx|  |  |xx|  |  |xx|
|  |xx|xx|xx|11|  |xx|  |  |xx|
|  |xx|xx|xx|xx|03|xx|  |  |xx|
|  |xx|xx|xx|xx|  |xx|05|  |xx|
|  |xx|xx|xx|xx|  |xx|  |06|xx|
|08|xx|xx|xx|xx|  |xx|  |  |xx|
|  |xx|xx|xx|xx|09|xx|  |  |xx|
|  |xx|xx|xx|xx|  |xx|10|  |xx|
|  |xx|xx|xx|xx|  |xx|  |11|xx|
|02|xx|xx|xx|xx|  |xx|  |xx|xx|
|  |xx|xx|xx|xx|05|xx|  |xx|xx|
|  |xx|xx|xx|xx|  |xx|08|xx|xx|
|09|xx|xx|xx|xx|  |xx|  |xx|xx|
|  |xx|xx|xx|xx|10|xx|  |xx|xx|
|  |xx|xx|xx|xx|  |xx|11|xx|xx|
|01|xx|xx|xx|xx|  |xx|xx|xx|xx|
|  |xx|xx|xx|xx|04|xx|xx|xx|xx|
|07|xx|xx|xx|xx|  |xx|xx|xx|xx|
|  |xx|xx|xx|xx|10|xx|xx|xx|xx|
|11|xx|xx|xx|xx|  |xx|xx|xx|xx|
Bot #6 is the winner
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/76358/discussion-on-question-by-akozi-bots-playing-a-counting-game).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## [JavaScript (Node.js)](https://nodejs.org), <strike>269</strike> <strike>245</strike> <strike>240</strike> <strike>233</strike> <strike>232</strike> 231 bytes

- thanks to @Kevin Cruijssen for reducing by 1 byte

```javascript
N=>{for(S=d=[],D=n=i=0;D<N-1;){for(R=n>8?1:(n>7?2:3)*Math.random()+1|0;R--;)S+="|"+[...Array(N)].map((x,I)=>i^I?d[I]?"xx":"  ":++n>9?n:"0"+n).join`|`+`|
`
for(n>10&&(d[i]=++D,n=0);d[i=++i%N];);}return S+`Bot #${i+1} is the winner`}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VY1BT4MwGEDv/Iqm6tLPQgPuoFIL0XDhIIdxJBjIANdl@7oUVMzgt@P05vG9d3j7@rPut1afBg9N0y6dWjIVnTtjWa4aVZRuolBp5cvkKfMCCX9pozB6iIOQYXQf34VruH2th52wNTbmyIAHky83nich54pOlBdCiGdr62@WQSmO9Ymx0U1BRfotjZsiLWM6jjSkhNCQc4weYwypTzmC2BuN1VTxanIq5/eNUeCvVqwpdKk4T1xUPsgLXUDfZKUEOdt2@LBIcl69mIFcXZ81D2aiezLsWvKlEVtbzcvWYG8OrTiYd9axNYDz3wQ@wPID)

Comment: You can save a byte by removing the new-line at `)\nS+=`.

Answer (score 4):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), <s>295</s> <s>291</s> 290 bytes

```python
from random import*
n=input()
r=range(n)
p=r[:]
b=[1]*n;s='%02d'
def P(l):print'|%s|'%'|'.join(l)
P(s%-~j for j in r)
x=0
while sum(b)>1:i=p.pop(0);g=choice(range(x+1,11)[:3]or[11]);P([2*'x '[b[j]],s%g][j==i]for j in r);x=g%11;b[i]=g<11;p+=[i]*b[i]
print'Bot #%d is the winner'%-~b.index(1)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TY6xboMwFEV3f4WlyrJNUoTpBn0d@gXslocSHHgo2JZxFCqh/jp1laXTvTp3ODd8p8m7@jiu0S80frkhBy7Bx1QQB@jCPQlJIuRptMJJEiDqxpAetDKFa1fgrKoHTgZ7pZ24ySZEdInvbN054zsvZ48uc9KJlb3@zPTqI50pOhol2aAijwlvlq73RfTyQzUIoQw@iEq2I1wmjxcrnvLtpM5KSd28GR@1Uka2ndB1wTfKda9nY84rG42eAdD8s7QbjEypttdoYHzPLZwg9@IPkOfdT5/oCxsorjRNlj7QORt5/tuX6Aa7CSWPo65@AQ)

- -1 byte, thanks to Kevin Cruijssen

Comment: You can save a byte by making a variable for `'%02d'` which you are using twice.

Comment: No problem. I keep golfing just 1 or 2 bytes from your answers lol.. Just goes to show how well golfed your answers already are for my concise Python knowledge. ;)

Answer (score 2):

## [C (clang)](http://clang.llvm.org/), <s>288</s> <s>283</s> <s>282</s> 266 bytes

```c
f(n){int i,j,p[99]={},m,k,x;for(i=j=k=0;k<n;printf("|%02d",k++));for(puts("|"),m=n;x=i>7?10-i:3,i=x?clock()%x-~i:0,m>1;){for(k=~0;++k<n;printf(p[k]?"|xx":k-j?"|  ":"|%02d",i?i:11));puts("|"),!i&&m--*p[j]++;do j++,j%=n;while(p[j]);}printf("Bot #%d is the winner",j);}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TVHLboMwELz7K7ZURHZsBLSHKjgOUn8jzYHyaBYHgwhRkEjy69TQps3N6xnPzI5TLz0k5mscC2rYgKYDFKVotqvVTg1XUQktelnULUVVKq0CqddGNq0lFtS5uMFL5gjNOWMzqTl1R3vtMFEpI3uFm7c4DDyMXgWqPk4Pdaopc3vvhlEgqk0o2TC90@oWSM4ftJut3sXOpe@dSHulPQE40d0QY4zC0Hr@@z3hYlF53rLZljvOZVZDybkoXRvjvMdDTieAyes9@nvdwbObAR6h2@dwRmPy1hGlpYy@/2nRtM5ykshPimwgkDzsItu8O7UGkr@FknkhSa6EkKnDKkFDGQzEX5IftS4/djOEksx1goJAAsIawlCibdCy4Z7OBvM24GYfxhH2Q2AKwSb5pU9IQcPADr8hJtfxGw)

Bots are 0 indexed.

Following will do 1-indexed for+2 bytes

```c
f(n){int i,j,p[99]={},m,k,x;for(i=j=k=0;k<n;printf("|%02d",++k));for(puts("|"),m=n;x=i>7?10-i:3,i=x?clock()%x-~i:0,m>1;){for(k=~0;++k<n;printf(p[k]?"|xx":k-j?"|  ":"|%02d",i?i:11));puts("|"),!i&&m--*p[j]++;do j++,j%=n;while(p[j]);}printf("Bot #%d is the winner",j+1);}
```

Comment: [257 bytes](https://tio.run/##TZHLboMwEEX3/oqRKyQcbAHtogqOg9TfSFkQHu3gYBAhKhIkv04NTaqs/Jjre8@MM5GdUvM1z6Vr2IimB@QVbw/bbaLGK6@55oMsm85FVSmtAql3RradFZYunZzgNadcex5jq6i99Gd7TRmvlZGDwv17HAYCozeOaoizU5NplzmDuGEU8Hofyv8XbFwMtLoF0vOeQtqDTmI6DQONtKjsDoBGj2SMMQrDezhOUy3Epj1UiedJuyhxqxyTSCavD@KPpocXJwc8Q/9dwA8aU3SUV1Yy@/7RVrMmL0gqjy6ykUD61ILsiv7SGUj/@0jXPiS5EkKW0dUpGpfBSPwN@XPri3O/llCSlREUBBIQdhCGEu3grBoedBZM7MHJPw3l9h9ggWCL/cYnpHTDwB7uEEvq/As "C (clang) – Try It Online")

Answer (score 1):

## VBA (Excel), 551 bytes

`CellA1` as input and output in immediate window.

```vb
Sub k()
Z = [A1] - 1
ReDim p(Z)
For b = 0 To Z
p(b) = "  "
Next
Do Until i = Z
Do Until a >= 11
Randomize
a = a + CInt(IIf(a > 8, 1, IIf(a > 7, 1 + Rnd, 1 + (Rnd * 2))))
Do Until p(d) = a
p(y) = IIf(p(y) = "xx", p(y), a)
d = y
y = IIf(y = Z, 0, y + 1)
Loop
For b = 0 To Z
c = c & IIf(p(b) < 10, 0 & p(b), p(b)) & "|"
g = IIf(p(b) = "  ", b, g)
p(b) = IIf(p(b) = "xx", "xx", "  ")
Next
Debug.Print "|" & c
Application.Wait Now + #12:00:01 AM#
DoEvents
c = ""
Loop
p(d) = "xx"
i = i + 1
a = 0
Loop
Debug.Print "Bot #" & g + 1 & " is the winner."
End Sub
```